# Is there a way to broadcast ndarray of different shapes into a single ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, dimensions, shap

### Here a simple snippet of what I mean:

```
nested = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
​
scalar1= np.array([[1],[2]])
scalar2= np.array([[1],[3]])
scalar3= np.array([[1],[4]])
​
nesting = np.array([nested,scalar1,scalar2],dtype='object')
```

Here the error printed:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2,)

### About the context:

I'm working on a Fake News Detector of tweets, using a Neural Net that takes 2 inputs, a text sequence input, `xtrain_pad`  of **shape (1300,1500)**, and a numerical static input, `X_train_static` of **shape (1300,7)**.
Give this as two separate inputs to the Keras model I'm using it's not a problem, you can just put that as a list:

```
model.fit([xtrain_pad,X_train_static], y_train, 
                        epochs=epochs, 
                        batch_size=batch_size, 
                        validation_split=0.1, 
                        verbose=0,
                        validation_data=([xval_pad,X_val_static, y_val]),
                        callbacks=callback)
```

But now I'm trying to estimate the importance of the features using *Shap*.
To do so the constructor to build a Shap explainer, like `DeepExplainer` is:

```
DE = shap.DeepExplainer(model, data = [xtrain_pad,X_train_static])
```

But the method accept as `data` only `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame` format, and here my problem to transform 2 inputs into a single ndarray.

I've searched alternative approaches to tackle this, like using DataFrame or searching other Shap explainer, but none seems to work.

Comment: Do it like `np.c_[xtrain_pad, X_train_static]` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (I think) is *concatenating* or *stacking* not broadcasting.

If you had searched for how to concatenate or stack arrays horizontally you would probably have found:

```
nesting = np.hstack([nested,scalar1,scalar2])
```

or

```
nesting = np.concatenate([nested,scalar1,scalar2], axis=1)
```

*Note*: Bear in mind these operations will make a copy of the data though so make sure you have enough memory...

Answer (score 0):

```
In [40]: nested = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
    ...: scalar1= np.array([[1],[2]])
    ...: scalar2= np.array([[1],[3]])
    ...: scalar3= np.array([[1],[4]])
```

You have a (2,3) and (2,1) arrays.

When the component arrays have a matching first dimensions we get errors like this:

```
In [41]: np.array([nested, scalar1], object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [41] in <cell line: 1>
    np.array([nested, scalar1], object)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2,)
```

That `broadcasting` error is internal to `np.array`, a result of trying to map the first array, the (2,3) one, into a target of shape (2,). It's a bit obscure, but just says, using `np.array` this way does not work.

When combining (2,3),(2,1) and (1,2) it works. The arrays don't all match on the first dimension.

```
In [42]: np.array([nested, scalar1, scalar2.T], object)
Out[42]: 
array([array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]]), array([[1],
                                  [2]]), array([[1, 3]])], dtype=object)
```

When the shapes match, the result can be 3d, not 1d object:

```
In [43]: np.array([scalar1, scalar2], object)
Out[43]: 
array([[[1],
        [2]],

       [[1],
        [3]]], dtype=object)
In [44]: _.shape
Out[44]: (2, 2, 1)
```

To reliably make an object dtype array of arrays you have to do something like:

```
In [45]: res = np.empty(4, object)
In [46]: res[:] = [nested, scalar1, scalar2, scalar3]
In [47]: res
Out[47]: 
array([array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]]), array([[1],
                                  [2]]), array([[1],
                                                [3]]), array([[1],
                                                              [4]])],
      dtype=object)
```

However the `fit` might not like that.  Usually it expects a n-d array with numeric dtype.  You could for example, combine the 'scalar' into one (2,3) arrays, and then join that with the other (2,3) to make a (4,3), or a (2,2,3):

```
In [48]: np.hstack((scalar1, scalar2, scalar3))
Out[48]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 4]])
In [49]: np.vstack((nested, _))
Out[49]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Or you might have to pad the 'scalar' to (2,3), and make a (4,2,3) from that.

Or joining them all along the horizontal axis

```
In [50]: np.hstack((nested,scalar1, scalar2, scalar3))
Out[50]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Why so complex if he needs to concat `(1300,1500)` and `(1300,7)` ?

Comment: I was focusing on the error in his initial `np.array(...., object)` attempt.  The OP did not explain what `shap.DeepExplaine` expects, and I haven't tried to look it up.  Some how I doubt if a (1300,1507) shaped array is the answer, since it looses all distinction between the first 1500 columns and the last 7.

Comment: The source of the error is clearly stated. And this is what expected in ML (tensorflow) and XAI (shap)